# An error occurred. Detailed message: Invalid path: 'name/' VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new Git repository on VSTS with a `.gitignore` file (for Visual Studio) and cloned repo to my machine. I then created a ASP.NET Core web application in the cloned directory (thru VS 2015 w/Update 3) and started coding from there. I am now connected to the repo master branch, I am seeing that I have 74 uncommitted changes, but when I hit Commit All I get the following error:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: Invalid path: 'Ehi.Met.Client.Ng2/'
```

`Ehi.MetClient.Ng2` is the name of my Git repository and the folder I cloned to, as well as my solution and project file (there is only 1 project in my solution).

Also, when I run `git commit` through a cmd prompt, I see the following (I am not able to embed images yet, but see below):

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
        Ehi.Met.Client.Ng2.sln
        Ehi.Met.Client.Ng2/
        global.json
        src/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

I am unable to push my code to my VSTS repository, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a random guess - maybe VSTS doesn't like `.` in directory names?

Comment: From the command prompt, what happens if you do `git add .` and then `git commit`?

Comment: Scott, sorry for late reply, I fixed this a while ago and I am certain the command "git add ." fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this message while adding a solution to Git, with an included sub folder, created with angular cli (ng new pagename). I first build the full solution structure in visual studio, including creating my angular 4 app as a sub folder in the solution, using the angular cli tool. Then i added source control to the top level solution, and the commit was not able to added my angular project folder. This was because angular cli by default is adding git for your project, and therefor that folder was already under versioning control. I ended up creating my project in another order. 1) Create the solution, Add it to Source control and Git, THEN after that, add the angular folder with angular cli. Now angular cli will not create git binding, because the solution is already under source control. Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied a project to the current solution and the newly copied project was throwing this error, I found out that I should remove the .git folder from the newly copied project so there's only one master git repo and that fixed the problem.
another workaround is to move the new project to the outside of current solution and then move it back to solution folder.